# How does Google Cloud AI Platform allocate the resources in a given region, does it follow the quota restrictions?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a free amount of TPUs allocated for zone `us-central1-a`. But only for that specific zone.
When I setup Platform-ai jobs I can only specify a region (`us-central`).

Will the platform AI pick up a random region only based on availability? Is there a way I can restrict it to the given region?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: partially yes, the tip of selecting only the v2-32 that is restricted to the region was insightful. I will leave it open just few more days in case a google ai sees it, then I will close it

Comment: I checked with a GCP colleague and he said that that checks. You should not though expect official comments from Google. How resources are allocated can change in future and they won't monitor third party sites to ensure the information stays up to date.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you for following up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's clarify the naming convention: `us-central1-a` is a zone within `us-central1` region.

It's indeed based on availability. You cannot explicitly select the zone, only the region. If your free resources are bound to a zone, one way to make sure you stay on `us-central1-a` is to select a TPU class that is bound to that zone. At the time of writing, this would be:

- **v2-32** 256 GiB
- **v2-128** 1 TiB
- **v2-256** 2 TiB
- **v2-512** 4 TiB

Based on [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/types-zones). I'd check them from time to time to avoid nasty surprises. Typically though the customer service will be able to help you if you run into billing issues (you get caught in a different zone).